# Does rustdoc generate runnable binaries?

Tags: rust, code-coverage, rust-cargo, kcov

I'm trying to run [kcov](https://github.com/SimonKagstrom/kcov) on a Rust project. This works really well for usual tests, but I haven't been able to figure out how to make it find doc tests.

Does `rustdoc` create any binaries that I can pass to `kcov` to run coverage on?

Comment: From a quick browsing of the source, I think the answer will be "no", but I'll wait to see if someone more knowledgeable can answer. However, I would question the underlying premise. Examples in documentation exist to show consumers of your code how to use it in a easily-understandable manner. They are executed and validated mostly to prevent the examples from rotting over time. I wouldn't count a doc test as actually validating any functionality of the code, thus I wouldn't include it in coverage statistics.

Comment: Yeah, I would interpret doctests as testing the documentation, not the code. Coverage is implicitly 100% with doctests because it's testing all the code in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Rustdoc compiles binaries in a temporary directory and runs them immediately:

https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/acdd3b9f5a/src/librustdoc/test.rs#L248-L292

I think the `TempDir` destructor removes the temporary directory and its contents when the function end. There doesn’t seem to be any way to get at the binaries in order to run them in `kcov`.

Comment: There is. You can intercept them and copy them, but it's a pain to write.

Comment: Ok, let’s say no easy way :)